# Cannot get rid of @Autowired by using @RequiredArgsConstructor or @AllArgsConstructor

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection, lombok

I have the following code:

```
// @RequiredArgsConstructor
// @AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class AuthTokenFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Autowired
    private final JwtUtils jwtUtils;
    // private final JwtUtils jwtUtils;

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;
    // private final UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AuthTokenFilter.class);

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, 
        HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        try {
            String jwt = parseJwt(request);
            if (jwt != null && jwtUtils.validateJwtToken(jwt)) {
                String username = jwtUtils.getUserNameFromJwtToken(jwt);

                UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication =
                        new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                                userDetails,
                                null,
                                userDetails.getAuthorities());
                authentication.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));

                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Cannot set user authentication: {}", e);
        }

        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    private String parseJwt(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String headerAuth = request.getHeader("Authorization");

        if (StringUtils.hasText(headerAuth) && headerAuth.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            return headerAuth.substring(7, headerAuth.length());
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

I am trying to get rid of `@Autowired` by using `@RequiredArgsConstructor` or `@AllArgsConstructor` as commented in the code. However, as the final fields may not been initialized, I get error indicating this problem. For that, I may also set `jwtUtils` and `userDetailsService` as null, but I am not sure if it is a good idea. So, can I use a constructor annotation (lombok) to get rid of `@Autowired` in this example?

**Update:** When using the suggested approach, I get error in this bean in other class:

```
@Bean
public AuthTokenFilter authenticationJwtTokenFilter() {
    return new AuthTokenFilter();
}
```

**Expected 2 arguments but found 0** error

Comment: When you use `@Bean`, you should also pass the required beans like 
`publ...authenticationJwtTokenFilter(JwtUtils j, UserService(Impl) us) { // ... use'm in constructor: ...
    return new AuthTokenFilter(j, us);
}`

Comment: Good point, then the cleanest way is using `@Autowired`? Or is there a better solution for that?

Answer (score 1):

Just use constructor injection. If your bean has exactly one constructor, spring will behave as if it has `@Autowired`, even if it's not added explicitly.

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@Component
public class AuthTokenFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    private final JwtUtils jwtUtils;
    private final UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AuthTokenFilter.class);

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        //method implementation
    }
}
```

**Edit:** Add `@Component` on the class, spring will initialize the bean for you, no need to do it manually with `@Bean` (remove the entire method).

Comment: I also tried to remove that bean, but it causes another problems. So, could you download the github code and try by adding lombok dependency?

Comment: **By the way**, should I use `@RequiredArgsConstructor` instead of `@AllArgsConstructor` as the fields are marked `final` ? Any idea for that?

Comment: @Rosa The difference between [AllArgsConstructor](https://projectlombok.org/api/lombok/AllArgsConstructor) and [RequiredArgsConstructor](https://projectlombok.org/api/lombok/RequiredArgsConstructor) is explained in the docs. Yes, i mean remove the entire `@Bean` method. No, i can't download the project, it goes way beyond the scope of the current question. You can use the example code above, it compiles, `AuthTokenFilter` is now spring component and you can **autowire** it wherever it's needed. As a rule of thumb, if something is a spring component, autowire it, don't create new instances.

Comment: Thanks for your helps, voted up. But cannot solved the problem :(

Answer (score 0):

Starting with Spring version 4.3, the single bean constructor does not need to be annotated with the @Autowired annotation.
With Lombok, it's possible to generate a constructor for either all class's fields (with `@AllArgsConstructor`) or all final class's fields (with `@RequiredArgsConstructor`).